# JQgrid export lazing loading of data

Tags: jsp, jqgrid

I use struts2 and JQgrid without plugin. I need to export data to an Excel file. I set `loadOnce` as false pagination is on the server side.

For my export file I need it to contain all data from my database, I use `exportToExcel` function for jqgrid but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exportToExcel function work only on local data, which should be loaded either with loadonce true or with data parameter. More on this you can [read in documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/exporting/#common-rules)

In order to make export in this case you will need  to export the data at server side.